# What does the code <' mean in HTML?

Tags: html

i am working on an html parser, but when my program reads something like

```
<a href="http://www.cprogramming.com/"><' class="logo noprint" src="http://static.cprogramming.com/main_images/title.png" width="324" height="83" border="0">< /a>
```

It breaks. I know how to fix the problem , i would just like to know how to interpret the code, either invalid html or is a technique that i just have not as yet come across in my studies.

Comment: Just some bad HTML. Looks like an `<img>` tag someone screwed up.

Comment: Yes , it would appear so , thanks

Comment: @worlboss, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sample seems to be a clickable image link, and this <' does not have any meaning. the code has a missing img tag which I think was just removed by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You missed `img` element.

```
<a href="http://www.cprogramming.com/">
 <img class="logo noprint" src="http://static.cprogramming.com/main_images/title.png" width="324" height="83" border="0">
< /a>
```

> Note: You can find easily by yourself through W3c Validator.  https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input